# Engineering specs for converting AC to DC

Tags: capacitor, diodes, voltage-regulator, rectifier

I’m experimenting with electricity generation. I am generating 110V AC, wattage and amperage unknown (after a step down transformer from 400V), and I want to rectify the AC into around 130V DC to run a DC tool motor.

My understanding is I need a rectifier bridge, capacitor and a voltage regulator. Do I need anything else? And what specs do I shop for?

Super grateful for any help.  I’m out of my own wheelhouse but I’m learning.

Comment: What does your motor need?

Comment: You're only looking at voltages.  You need to know current and power requirements.   This DC motor could be a slot-car set, or it could be a bandsaw.   Or bigger.   You need to be much more specific.

Comment: I’ll humbly suggest that you should play around with voltages < 50VDC for a while to understand the basics before messing with 110VAC and the rectified DC out of that. There are a lot of little potential gotchas that can be quite dangerous. Maybe get a 24VAC or so output transformer and play with rectifying that and driving 12V motors. It should be a blast and very educational. Also, mistakes are far less likely to be really, really bad ones!